# 2SXC - SearchIndexException: Search: Error while indexing module

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm getting the dreaded DNN Error "An unexpected error has occurred" with a link to return to the site. There's no other information displayed here so I checked the logs under `\Portals\_default\Logs\` and found this:

```
2019-09-26 10:15:02.052-05:00 [XXXXXX][D:4][T:84][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - ToSic.SexyContent.Search.SearchIndexException: Search: Error while indexing module 450 on tab 44, portal 0 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at ToSic.Eav.Security.Permissions.PermissionCheckBase.DoesPermissionAllow(IEntity permissionEntity, Char[] desiredActionCode) in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Security\Permissions\PermissionCheckBase.cs:line 119
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
    at ToSic.SexyContent.SxcInstance.get_UserMayEdit() in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\SexyContent\SxcInstance_Render.cs:line 17
    at ToSic.SexyContent.ContentBlocks.ModuleContentBlock..ctor(IInstanceInfo instanceInfo, Log parentLog, ITenant tenant, IEnumerable`1 overrideParams) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\SexyContent\ContentBlocks\ModuleContentBlock.cs:line 66
    at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.Search.SearchController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(IInstanceInfo instance, DateTime beginDate) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc Dnn\Search\SearchController.cs:line 53
    at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.DnnBusinessController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime beginDate) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc Dnn\Environment\Dnn7\DnnBusinessController.cs:line 98
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.DnnBusinessController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime beginDate) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc Dnn\Environment\Dnn7\DnnBusinessController.cs:line 102
    at DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.IndexSearchDocuments(Int32 portalId, ScheduleHistoryItem schedule, DateTime startDateLocal, Action`1 indexer)
2019-09-26 10:15:02.069-05:00 [XXXXXX][D:4][T:84][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - ToSic.SexyContent.Search.SearchIndexException: Search: Error while indexing module 451 on tab 20, portal 0 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at ToSic.Eav.Security.Permissions.PermissionCheckBase.DoesPermissionAllow(IEntity permissionEntity, Char[] desiredActionCode) in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Security\Permissions\PermissionCheckBase.cs:line 119
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
    at ToSic.SexyContent.SxcInstance.get_UserMayEdit() in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\SexyContent\SxcInstance_Render.cs:line 17
    at ToSic.SexyContent.ContentBlocks.ModuleContentBlock..ctor(IInstanceInfo instanceInfo, Log parentLog, ITenant tenant, IEnumerable`1 overrideParams) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\ToSic.Sxc\SexyContent\ContentBlocks\ModuleContentBlock.cs:line 66
    at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.Search.SearchController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(IInstanceInfo instance, DateTime beginDate) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc Dnn\Search\SearchController.cs:line 53
    at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.DnnBusinessController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime beginDate) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc Dnn\Environment\Dnn7\DnnBusinessController.cs:line 98
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.DnnBusinessController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime beginDate) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc Dnn\Environment\Dnn7\DnnBusinessController.cs:line 102
    at DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.IndexSearchDocuments(Int32 portalId, ScheduleHistoryItem schedule, DateTime startDateLocal, Action`1 indexer)
```

Unfortunately, I haven't touched the site at all since a demo I did at the beginning of August where I created a sample post which means I have no idea what I did to cause the error. I didn't get any error messages at that time and after getting approval from the big wigs, I shifted my focus to other projects and don't recall doing anything usual or bumping into any errors. But I try to access the site today and I get these errors related to 2SXC.

**What do these errors mean and how can I fix the issue to restore my site?**

**Update:** I'm running DNN 9.1.1 and 2SXC 09.32.01 with the News app 03.01.04

**Update 2:** I just notices this error too:

```
2019-09-27 11:17:08.567-05:00 [XXXXXX][D:2][T:10][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: Unhandled error loading page. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: The file '/DesktopModules/DDRMenu/Menu.ascx' does not exist. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: The file '/DesktopModules/DDRMenu/Menu.ascx' does not exist. ---> System.Web.HttpException: The file '/DesktopModules/DDRMenu/Menu.ascx' does not exist.
    at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
    at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.GetReferencedType(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean allowNoCompile)
    at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.GetUserControlType(VirtualPath virtualPath)
    at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessUserControlRegistration(UserControlRegisterEntry ucRegisterEntry)
    at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive)
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal()
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()
    at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
    at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
    at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath)
    at DotNetNuke.UI.ControlUtilities.LoadControl[T](TemplateControl containerControl, String ControlSrc)
    at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.LoadSkin(PageBase page, String skinPath)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Which version of DNN? Which version of 2sxc?

Comment: @JoeCraig - See my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My problem actually had nothing to do with 2SXC.** In my Update 2 on the original question, I mentioned I had also noticed an error saying:

```
System.Web.HttpParseException: The file '/DesktopModules/DDRMenu/Menu.ascx' does not exist.
```

This apparently is a common problem with DNN module development in Visual Studio. From  [HemIT Blog](http://blog.hemit.fr/2013/07/dotnetnuke-cant-find-ddrmenumenu-ascx/):

> Where does this Virtual Directory come from? In my development environment, it comes from the following facts:
>
> - we are using SVN, and I tend to checkout the modules and compile them outside of my IIS websites
> - I am using the famous christoc template for module development (don't get me wrong, it's great! It's just doing things behind our back that we might not foresee).
>     Indeed, if I look in my project file:
>
> [image: visual studio image]
>
> The real culprit is Visual Studio!
>
> When you are checking your module out, if you have a site configured on IIS, project will open fine. However when you compile, if you are out of an IIS website, a virtual directory "desktopmodule" will get created, and hide the "DesktopModules" folder.
>
> Hence DNN can no longer find the DDRMenu module, hence it is failing.

**The solution was really simple. Go into IIS and remove the virtual directory labeled "desktopmodules":**

[image: delete virtual directory]